# Returning a MemitResult object and a function call when using memit magic in IPython

Tags: python, ipython, cell, google-colaboratory

So the issue I am having is that I want to measure the memory consumption and the time for a cell line in iPython on Google Colab, where the line is returning an object too.
I am doing this with `memory-profiler`, so I can store all results of the benchmark in a file automatically.

I found out that `memit -o` gives me a `MemitResult` object, but
the issue is that the object assignment gives an undefined `m̀odel`:

`NameError: name 'model' is not defined`

A short MWE:

```
%%time
import pmdarima as pm
trainMemory =  %memit  -o  model= pm.auto_arima(df["y"], seasonal=True, m=12, maxiter=10, njobs = -1)
```

Ideally I would assign all 3 variables, for time, memory and object in one train function call,
to save on the training time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I used [Weights and biases](https://docs.wandb.com/quickstart) for tracking GPU and  memory consumption at the same time.

The setup was really easy, however I haven't yet found how to extract information like maximum, mininum etc.

Setup:

```
import wandb
import pmdarima as pm
wandb.init()  
model= pm.auto_arima(df["y"], seasonal=True, m=12, maxiter=10, njobs = -1)
```

Then on the website, you can see the consumption over time of the run

[image: Dashboard for system usage]

It turns out you can get the maximum usage via the api instead of looking at charts

```
import wandb 
api = wandb.Api() 
run = api.run(f"YOURNAME/{wandb.run.name}/{wandb.run.id}") 
system_metrics = run.history(stream = 'events') print(system_metrics["system.gpu.0.memory"].max())
system_metrics.to_csv("metrics.csv")
```

You can then access the properties of the system_metrics object

Comment: [More API Info](https://docs.wandb.com/library/api/examples)